# Creating Database tables on the fly

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a web application in which I need to create a database tables on the fly. Those newly created tables will have a relationship with an already existing tables. I am using Java EE and Hibernate as a JPA implementation. the problem is how can I deal with those newly created tables as I don't know their names in advance (each table will be named for example "X + random number", X will be known in advance and the random number will be generated during the run time and stored in a database) how can I model those entities and how to map them?

I am thinking if I use the low level JDBC to manage this part of the application but this will force me to take care of things I normally don't while usng any ORM.

Is no-SQL databases can help me reach this approach?

Comment: No, no, no, no, no! Don't create tables on the fly. That is horrible.

Comment: So I have to reconsider my design. Do you have any helpful ideas? @juergend

Comment: No, I have not. Since you don't decribe what you do and what data you want to handle.

Comment: Did you try with invoking stored procedure to create table invoking with ORM mapper